# Is there a reason to use insertAdjacentHTML() over any of the equivalent jQuery functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am just learning JS/jQuery, and I came across [this page](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2013/10/06/inside-the-box-with-vanilla-javascript/?utm_source=buffer&utm_campaign=Buffer&utm_content=buffer5531a&utm_medium=twitter) which seems to advocate using vanilla JS instead of jQuery. Is there a valid reason to use insertAdjacentHTML() over something like .before() or .append()? Is there any situation where it's vastly preferable to use vanilla JS over jQuery, and if so, why?

Comment: You'll end up having to learn plain JS DOM anyway but if you use jQuery then I'd say just do it the jQuery way.

Comment: Thank you. I'm learning both regardless - I didn't word that clearly in the question.

Answer (score 3):

Typically you'll find that using native functions outperform jQuery functions. [Here's a JSPerf](http://jsperf.com/insertadjacenthtml-vs-jquery-append) comparing the speed of insertAdjacentHTML and jQuery's append. You can see that most of the time you get slightly better performance.

You should ask yourself how much performance matters in your app. Just how necessary is it to optimize your script? For most apps I don't think that you'll see any difference between jQuery's performance and native functions, even in cases when the difference in speed is more pronounced than between these two functions.

Learning about native equivalents to jQuery functions can still be valuable, though. There might be times when you do need to worry about performance to this degree. Or if you'd like to write code that doesn't rely on jQuery, perhaps for an open-source project. And there is no arguing that you are more likely to be a better Javascript programmer if you know the language and the native DOM as well as you know jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

jmeas is right about the performance. Another issue is the jQuery 90K load. However in most projects those issues are really small and jQuery will make your code faster, cleaner, smarter and elegant. My humble advice: Use jQuery for most projects unless you really have strange performance concerns or only needs a couple of vanilla js calls.